# How to Send data of dynamic fields created from a database in JSON format in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a form that has fixed fields as well as dynamic fields created from a database. the fields could be different every time.So how do i access a dynamic generated formControl value in in JSON format like this category object .

Output is :-

```
Category:[
  {
    "label": "test1",
    "measurements": {
        length:10,
        Shoulder:20,
        Chest: 20
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "test2",
    "measurements": {
        stomach:10,
        thigh:20 }
  }
]
```

[image]

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of clickCategoryData let pointIndex=index">
<p><b>{{item.label}}</b></p>
<div *ngFor="let measurement of item.measurements;">
<label>{{measurement.name}}</label>
<input type="number" class="box" [placeholder]="measurement.name" [id]="measurement.id"  required>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For example check this :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnzh3x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Only the key value pair of { length:10, Shoulder:20, Chest: 20 } changing?

Comment: yes. i want this change

Comment: plz check my stackblitz code .

Comment: ido you want changes for category array or for the clickCategoryData?

Comment: for clickCategoryData

Comment: but there is only id and name?

Comment: do you want change id and name?

Comment: array i have


[
  {
    "label": "test1",
    "measurements": [
      {
        "id": "5bdbdd128265ce4e4c74707f",
        "name": "length",
        
      },
      {
        "id": "5bdbdd378265ce4e4c747080",
        "name": "Shoulder"
      
      },
      {
        "id": "5bdbdd6a8265ce4e4c747081",
        "name": "Chest"
        
      }
    ]
  },
  ]

array i want:-

category:[
  {
    "label": "test1",
    "measurements": {
        length:10,
        Shoulder:20,
        Chest: 20
    }
  },
 
  ]

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vm61kq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: ah ok i understand what u want just wait

Comment: convert measurement array in object form.

Comment: { length:10, Shoulder:20, Chest: 20 }   so 10, 20 its value of form feild ...  not id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert your existing array to output array which you want as this

```
this.clickCategoryData.forEach(
      data => {
        let jsonObj = {}
        data.measurements.forEach(mes => jsonObj[mes.name] = "")
          data.measurements = jsonObj
      }
    )
```

here is the [stackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vm61kq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: click submit and and see the console. :)

Comment: hlo sir ,
can u plz help me @Asanka

Comment: i have a problem to setValue to checkbox .
i will provide u stackblitz link for reviewing the problem.@Asanka